# How to upload a CSV file to firebase storage using cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

**Question :**

Is there a way to pass a CSV file that is uploaded, to a cloud function and upload that to the firebase storage?

**Current Implementation**

```
let fileToUpload = this.state.originalFile
        
const addedStorageDetails = await axios.post(
    'https://us-central1-silo-prod.cloudfunctions.net/addFileToStorage', // TOCHANGE: You should probably make this an environment variable
    fileToUpload
);
console.log('File uploaded to added to Storage successfully at location: ',addedStorageDetails);
console.log('Data', addedDataResults);
```

I am passing the CSV file as fileToUpload.

Cloud function code:

```
exports.addFileToStorage = functions.https.onCall((data,context)=>{
    let bucketName = "Files"
    let name = "NameOfCSVFile" //Is there a way to get the name?
    let fileToUpload = data
    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`${bucketName}/${name}`)
    let uploadTask = storageRef.put(fileToUpload)
    uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,()=>{
       let downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL
       console.log('File uploaded to added to Storage successfully at location: ',downloadURL);
       console.log('File', fileToUpload)
    })
})
```

**Error:**

```
Request has incorrect Content-Type. application/x-www-form-urlencoded 

Invalid request IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: true,
     ended: true,
     endEmitted: true,
     reading: false,
     sync: false,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     destroyed: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: false, //Theres more, very long.
```

Comment: If you're trying to pass the name of a file to a callable function, that's not going to work.  You will need to somehow pass the actual contents of the file. It's probably easier if you just make the client upload directly to the bucket.

Comment: How do I pass the actual content?

Comment: Do you have the filename value in your client? If so, the solution that Doug proposed above of making the upload directly from the client is the best option for you.

Comment: Got it done, thanks guys!

Comment: Glad to hear it @Vijay, I would recommend that you write your solution to an answer here so that anyone in the community facing the same issue can refer to it and you, and also so you can get some repution, so it's a  win win situation :)